# Filter MySQL table using data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have one table containing "user sessions" and another to indicate violations in the system. One possible violation is having a user logged on for more than 12 hours straight.

The tables are as followed:

```
notification:
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| host_id      | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| alert_id     | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| event_start  | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time_noticed | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| info         | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| seen         | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

login:
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| host_id  | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| start    | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| end      | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The conditions I want for the result table are:
login.last = 1, login.host_id=X, end>start+12hours
and to make sure I didn't report this instance before:
login.host_id!=notification.host_id, notification.alert_id!=Y, login.start!=notification.event_start, login.username!=notification.info
(in other words, I don't want to get another report of the same user, on the same host, making the same violation which started at the same time)

Comment: What did you try already that didn't work?

Comment: SELECT username, start FROM login LEFT OUTER JOIN notification ON (login.host_id != notification.host_id OR alert_id != $alert_id OR start != event_start OR username != info) WHERE end>DATE_ADD(start,INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND login.host_id=$host_id AND last=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT username, start 
FROM login 
LEFT OUTER JOIN notification ON 
    (login.host_id = notification.host_id 
    AND login.start = notification.event_start
    AND login.username = notification.info) 
WHERE 
    end>DATE_ADD(start,INTERVAL 12 HOUR) 
    AND login.host_id=$host_id 
    AND last=1 
    AND login.id IS NULL
```

This query should use "not exist" type of search (try EXPLAIN) which is good for the query performance.
maybe it worth to put UNIQUE KEY on notification 'host_id,event_started,info' and use INSERT IGNORE